# Text replacement in gulp test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, build, gulp, mocha.js

I am trying to create a gulp build system so that I can test both src file and the minimized file. Say I have `foo.src.js` and `foo.min.js`, my test file is `test.js`, which contains something like

```
var Foo = require(../FOO);
...
```

Then in my gulp file I have

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');

gulp.task('test-prepare', function() {
  return gulp.src('test.js')
    .pipe(replace(/FOO/g, 'foo'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('test-build-prepare', function() {
  return gulp.src('test.js')
    .pipe(replace(/FOO/g, 'foo.min'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('test', ['test-prepare'], function() {
  return gulp.src('build/test.js').pipe(mocha());
});

gulp.task('test-build', ['test-build-prepare'], function() {
  return gulp.src('build/test.js').pipe(mocha());
});
```

After I run `gulp test` I can see that build folder and the `test.js` file has the `FOO` been replaced with `foo` correctly. However the test is not running correctly as there is zero test cases been run. It shows:

```
[12:04:44] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/genEnum/gulpfile.js
[12:04:44] Starting 'test-prepare'...
[12:04:44] Finished 'test-prepare' after 23 ms
[12:04:44] Starting 'test'...


  0 passing (0ms)

[12:04:44] Finished 'test' after 5.82 ms
```

Anyone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. In my code it was not 'build/test.js', instead it was `BUILD_PATH+TEST_FILE`. While `BUILD_PATH` is `./build` and `TEST_FILE` is `test.js`, and there miss one `/` after they concatenated.

Changing it to `BUILD_PATH + '/' + TEST_FILE` fixed the issue and now I can run the test against both src file and minimized file.

BTW the gulpfile.js I referred to in this question could be found at https://github.com/greenlaw110/enumjs/blob/master/gulpfile.js